# What forms of address are used between criminals/suspected criminals and law enforcement/interrogators?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, pronombres, formalidad

Primero mi pregunta en español:

**¿Qué formas de apelativo se usan entre criminales/presuntos delincuentes y la policía/interrogadores?**

**Details in English:**

Recently I’ve been reviewing the various forms of address throughout Latin America.  Most of it seems pretty straightforward (except for when it isn’t such as certain pockets where it differs from the norm).  None of it really compelled me to post a question here, but tonight I was watching the latest episode of [***Criminal Minds***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criminal_Minds) – the episode titled “Mirror Image.”  And, as happens in almost every episode, an agent interrogates an “unsub” (aka suspect).

This particular episode made me think of forms of address because I also happened to recently read somewhere that criminals don’t use formal address when in the midst of a crime, so don’t expect to hear, “Por favor, déme usted su cartera, señor/señora,” if someone is trying to take your money.  Understandable.  But tonight’s *Criminal Minds* episode made me wonder what form of address law enforcement uses with a criminal or suspected criminal and even beyond that, what professional interrogators use in Latin American countries (especially since in this episode an agent has to interrogate/interview someone who is pretending to be her brother).

Is there a standard protocol to begin with "usted"" rather than "tú?"  Or does it just depend on the situation?  Is there anyone with firsthand/secondhand experience who can shed some light on this?  Or someone who’s watched a lot of Latin American/Spanish-language crime shows?

I have skimmed through the following publication:

[**Understanding Discourse Markers in Interpreter-Mediated Police Interviews**](http://usir.salford.ac.uk/30671/2/Gallai_PhD_Text_and_Appendices.pdf)

which is a very interesting read and it does touch on this subject somewhat, but it doesn’t directly/specifically answer my question other than to say that first names are often used to build rapport.

I appreciate any insight – personal experience or otherwise – you can provide on this topic.

**Detalles en español:**

Recientemente he estado reexaminando las diferentes formas de apelativo por Latinoamérica.  La mayoría de ello parece bastante sencillo (excepto para cuando no es tal como algunos focos donde difiera de la norma).  Nada de ello me impulsó a publicar una pregunta aquí, pero esta noche estaba mirando el último episodio de Criminal Minds – el episodio titulado, “Mirror Image.”  Y, como pasa en casi cada episodio, un agente interroga un “sudes” (aka sospechoso).

Este particular episodio me hizo pensar en formas de apelativo porque también pasé leer recientemente en algún lugar que criminales no usan apelativo formal cuando en medio de un crimen, así que no espere oír, “Please, give me your wallet, sir/ma’am,” si alguien está intentando tomar su dinero.  Entendible.  Pero el episodio de *Criminal Minds* esta noche me hizo preguntarme qué forma de apelativo la policía usa con un criminal o presunto delincuente e incluso más allá, qué forma de apelativo interrogadores usan en países Latinoaméricanos (especialmente desde en este episodio un agente tiene que interrogar/entrevistar alguien que se pretende ser su hermano.)

¿Hay un protocolo estándar comenzar con “usted” en lugar de “tú?”  ¿O sólo depende en la situación?  ¿Hay alguien con experiencia de primera o segunda mano que puede arrojar alguna luz en esto?  ¿O alguien que ha visto muchos programas de crímenes de Latinoamérica/en el idioma español?

He desnatada por la siguiente publicación:

[**Understanding Discourse Markers in Interpreter-Mediated Police Interviews**](http://usir.salford.ac.uk/30671/2/Gallai_PhD_Text_and_Appendices.pdf)

que es una lectura muy interesante, y toca en este tema en alguna medida, pero no respuesta directamente/específicamente mi pregunta aparte de decir que apellidos se usan a menudo construir compenetración.

Aprecio cualquier información – experiencia personal o de lo contrario – puede proveer en este tema.

Comment: En mi limitada experiencia en España (poner una denuncia), siempre formal ("usted") por ambas partes. Aunque puede haber influido mi avanzada edad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como normal general se usa `usted` y sus formas verbales p. ej. `podría`, cuando no existe una relación personal cercana o existe cierta formalidad en la conversación. Sin embargo en varios países de Latinoamérica se usa en exceso el `usted` en cualquier clase de conversación, incluso de una madre a un hijo.

Nótese también que en la mayoría de los casos no se usa directamente el pronombre `usted/ustedes` pero sus formas verbales o las partículas `le` en vez de `te` para verbos transitivos.

En la situación específica que se comenta. Un ladrón en México le podría perfectamente decir `¡Deme (usted) el bolso!` en vez de `¡Dame (tu) el bolso!`. Pero no así en España.

En la relación con los cuerpos de seguridad o cualquier otro profesional donde no se tenga una relación personal cercana, es muy probable que solo se use las formas de `usted` en España.

Comment: Muy interesante, @Veikrand.  Gracias por su respuesta.